# Splitting String and put it on int array

Tags: java, arrays, string, int

I have to input a string with numbers ex: 1,2,3,4,5.
That's a sample of the input, then I have to put that in an array of INT so I can sort it but is not working the way it should work.

```
package array;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Array {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input;
        int length, count, size;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        input = keyboard.next();
        length = input.length();
        size = length / 2;
        int intarray[] = new int[size];
        String strarray[] = new String[size];
        strarray = input.split(",");

        for (count = 0; count < intarray.length ; count++) {
            intarray[count] = Integer.parseInt(strarray[count]);
        }

        for (int s : intarray) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "not working the way it should work" in what way? error? doesn't work in the face of bad inputs? s is always empty?

Comment: `strArr = input.split(',')` then just copy strArr to an intArr

Answer (score 61):

For input `1,2,3,4,5` the input is of length 9. `9/2 = 4` in integer math, so you're only storing the first four variables, not all 5.

Even if you fixed that, it would break horribly if you passed in an input of `10,11,12,13`

It would work (by chance) if you used `1,2,3,4,50` for an input, strangely enough :-)

You would be much better off doing something like this

```
String[] strArray = input.split(",");
int[] intArray = new int[strArray.length];
for(int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
    intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(strArray[i]);
}
```

For future reference, when you get an error, I highly recommend posting it with the code. You might not have someone with a jdk readily available to compile the code to debug it! :)

Answer (score 42):

Java 8 offers a streams-based alternative to manual iteration:

```
int[] intArray = Arrays.stream(input.split(","))
    .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
    .toArray();
```

Be prepared to catch `NumberFormatException` if it's possible for the input to contain character sequences that cannot be converted to an integer.

Comment: Note For Android Developer, you also need min SDK version 24 along with Java 8

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider that you have input as "1,2,3,4".

That means the length of the input is 7. So now you write the size = 7/2 = 3.5. But as size is an `int`, it will be rounded off to 3.  In short, you are losing 1 value.

If you rewrite the code as below it should work:

```
String input;
int length, count, size;
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
input = keyboard.next();
length = input.length();

String strarray[] = input.split(",");
int intarray[] = new int[strarray.length];

for (count = 0; count < intarray.length ; count++) {
    intarray[count] = Integer.parseInt(strarray[count]);
}

for (int s : intarray) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing Integer division, so you will lose the correct length if the user happens to put in an odd number of inputs - that is one problem I noticed.  Because of this, when I run the code with an input of '1,2,3,4,5,6,7' my last value is ignored...

Answer (score 0):

```
String input = "2,1,3,4,5,10,100";
String[] strings = input.split(",");
int[] numbers = new int[strings.length];
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
{
  numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(strings[i]);
}
Arrays.sort(numbers);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
```

Comment: I'd recommend you use this instead:
numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(strings[i].trim())
otherwise if the string was " 4,22,42" it would throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Change the order in which you are doing things just a bit.  You seem to be dividing by 2 for no particular reason at all.

While your application does not guarantee an input string of semi colon delimited variables you could easily make it do so:

```
package com;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Good practice to initialize before use
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = "";
        // it's also a good idea to prompt the user as to what is going on
        keyboardScanner : for (;;) {
            input = keyboard.next();
            if (input.indexOf(",") >= 0) { // Realistically we would want to use a regex to ensure [0-9],...etc groupings 
                break keyboardScanner;  // break out of the loop
            } else { 
                keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
                continue keyboardScanner; // recreate the scanner in the event we have to start over, just some cleanup
            }
        }

        String strarray[] = input.split(","); // move this up here      
        int intarray[] = new int[strarray.length];

        int count = 0; // Declare variables when they are needed not at the top of methods as there is no reason to allocate memory before it is ready to be used
        for (count = 0; count < intarray.length; count++) {
            intarray[count] = Integer.parseInt(strarray[count]);
        }

        for (int s : intarray) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The divide by 2 is there because of the assumption that for each number, there is a corresponding comma. Of course, we know this is a flawed assumption, but I'm sure that was OP's line of thinking at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
   String N = "ABCD";
   char[] array = N.toCharArray();

   // and as you can see:
    System.out.println(array[0]);
    System.out.println(array[1]);
    System.out.println(array[2]);
  }
```

Comment: @Downvoters, at least comment the reason for downvoting.

Comment: @K_7 " input a string with numbers ex: `1,2,3,4,5`" not "ABCD"

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(arr.split(",")));
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (String s : stringList) 
   intList.add(Integer.valueOf(s));
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question is about creating an int array, not a `List<Integer>`.