# When I split a String input into an array, the array only has 1 Element. Why is that?

Tags: java, arrays, input, split

When I split a String input into an array, the array only has 1 Element. Why is that? Been at this since yesterday, I have yet to find a solution. I used this to help me a bit [Splitting String and put it on int array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348591/splitting-string-and-put-it-on-int-array)

```
class ISBNcheck2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter input: "); //ask for input
        String input = keyboard.nextLine(); // read input
        int length = input.length();

        String[] strArray = input.split(" "); //<---- THIS IS A PROBLEM, MY GUESS.
        // SOMEHOW strARRAY and intARRAY ONLY HAVE 1 ELEMENT STORED.?????

        int[] intArray = new int[strArray.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
            intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(strArray[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(intArray.length); // just a check
            System.out.println(intArray[i]); // just a check
        }

        //System.out.println();
        if (isIntegerclass.isValidISBN(input) && length == 10) {
            System.out.println("True: ");

            // I WANT TO BE ABLE TO ACCESS THE ELEMENTS LIKE THIS. BUT IT HAS ONLY 1 ELEMENT FOR SOME STRANGE REASON.
            System.out.println(" " + intArray[0] + " - " + intArray[1] + " " + intArray[2] + " " + intArray[3] + " - " + intArray[4] + " " + intArray[5] + " " + intArray[6] + " " + intArray[7] + " " + intArray[8] + " - " + intArray[9]); //print
        } else {
            System.out.println("This is not the right input...");
            System.out.println("The number must be 10 letters(numbers only) long. No need for dashes in between.");
            System.out.println("[] - [][][] - [][][][][] - []");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is just the main, i have another class to check if the input is only integers. But that class works. Just in case you're wondering about the reference to it in the if statement.

Comment: What are you passing in Scanner Input?

Comment: String containing 10 numbers. Like this: 1234567899

Comment: you need to 1) post only the relevant parts of the program 2) post the input for which the program is not working and 3) post the exact output/error that you're not understanding.

Comment: Than How can you expect more elements as your String don't have any space! :)

Comment: @ErikAllik yeah sorry :( i'll keep it in mind next time... Just thought it helps to see all the code :( most of it at least.

Comment: @TAsk yeah... that was the thing i needed to change :) thanks for the answers guys.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to just convert the string to a char array? `char[] charArr = input.toCharArray();` seing as char is compatible with int, it would be easier to parse that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this splits the input the way you want it. Spitting on "" treats each digit as a separate String. However, that generates on extra empty String before the first digit. The copyOfRange drops the extra.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {
  public static final void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    String[] raw = "01234".split("");
    String[] strArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(raw, 1, raw.length);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strArray));
  }
}
```

prints:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Thank you! :D only needed to change 1 space lmao.