# changing String to array and to integers in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, integer

If

```
String a="1,2,3,4,5"
```

I want to remove the commas in the string, and

change the string to an array, then

change every character of the array to integers, finally

apply any operation to the integers.

Is that possible?

I have this so far:

```
    String input;
    input = txtField.getText();
    String[] a = new String[input.length()];
    a = input.split(",");
            for(int i=0;i==input.length();i++){
                String c = a[i];
                txtField.setText(String.valueOf(a));
            }
```

Comment: yes, it's possible, but we would like to see what you have tried so far

Comment: yes it's possible

Comment: Yes what did you try? Stack Overflow is not an 'ask-it-and-we-do-it-for-you'-site.

Comment: And someone up-voted the question. How **useful** is it really to know if that is *possible*?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could not divide the integers by 0 - so no.

Comment: I presume you would also like to know how to accomplish this if it is possible. Yes it is possible, and it has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348591/splitting-string-and-put-it-on-int-array/46971651)

Comment: what is that mean, possible in java? you just want to convert a string to an integer, I think it's simple logic and possible in almost every language

Comment: `int[] intArray = Arrays.stream(a.split(",")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).map(i->anyOperation(i)).toArray();`

Comment: *cough*String.split()*cough*

Comment: I have made a full code but i cant put my answer here because its marked as duplicated.

Answer (score -1):

it is, you could use a method which basically removes all commas(.split)so you get a String without commas, and later take that string and use a for loop to go through each char and parse to int.

Comment: You get a what .....??

Comment: public static int[] arrayOfIntegers(String s) {
        int[] array;
        String newString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) != ',') {
                newString += s.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        String[] strArray = newString.split(" ");
        array = new int[newString.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
            array[i] = Integer.parseInt(strArray[i]);
        }
        return array;
    }

Comment: Here is the full code, i cant post here as i said someone has marked this as duplicated so there is no option to putting my answer in better formation.