# How to pass a string with comma separated values as function parameters in JAVA

Tags: java, string

I have a method that accepts any number of INTEGER parameters:
`pages(int,int...)`

This method is to select some pages of PDF file.

Book Pages stored as a string type like this:

```
String pages = "1,2,3,6,9";
```

I want to make this string as the parameter of the method to look like:

```
pages(1,2,3,6,9);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting String and put it on int array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348591/splitting-string-and-put-it-on-int-array)

Comment: Use varargs, or pass in a collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be easily done with streams:

```
Stream
  .of(commaSeparated.split(","))
  .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
  .toArray();
```

You can combine this with varargs to get what you want:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
  String commaSeparated = "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9";
  int[] arguments =
    Stream
      .of(commaSeparated.split(","))
      .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
      .toArray();
  pages(arguments);
}

public static void pages(int... numbers) {
  System.out.println("numbers: " + Arrays.toString(numbers));
}
```

Output will be:

```
numbers: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Note: of course varargs isn't needed in this specific case, it's useful only if you plan to call the same method with a variable number of `int` arguments, otherwise you can just change its signature to `pages(int[] numbers)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works for me!
as I'm new to programming and I'm using java in android programming.
when I implement this solution it asked me to upgrade my language from v7 to v8 with lambda.
what does it mean??

Comment: @IsamH.Abuaqlain It means that support for Streams was added starting from java 8 along with support for [lambdas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html), so you can't use java 7 if you want to use Streams, you have to upgrade to java 8

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Do this :

```
public class Test {
   public static void main(String..args) {
        String pages = "1,2,3,6,9";
        String[] pagesArr = pages.split(",");
         pages(pagesArr);
   }

  static void pages(String... pagesArr) {
       int[] array = Arrays.asList(pagesArr).stream().mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
       for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(array[i]);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer! I like the other one as well. It does not convert the array to a List first since a stream can be made from an array.